# Javascript dropdown for touch devices

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make the submenu open and close by class `toggle`.

WHy is the class `on` not toggled on click, to hide the submenu?

```js
var u = document.querySelector('ul');
var l = u.querySelectorAll("li");
var a = u.querySelectorAll('li.hasul > a');

for(var i=0; i<a.length;i++){
  a[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    l.forEach(function(i,n){
      i.classList.remove('on');
    });
    event.target.parentNode.classList.toggle('on');
   });
}
```

```css
ul{display:flex; list-style:none;}
li{margin:5px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
}
li ul{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  top: 40px;
  display: none;
}
li.on{
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
li.on ul{
  display: block;
}
a{text-decoration:none;display:block; padding: 5px;}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="hasul"><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="hasul"><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

https://codepen.io/felixaj/pen/poyyper

Comment: What does `l.forEach()` part do? Removing it seems to make the program work as expected

Comment: @Abhishek how to remove "on" class on other siblings when one menu is open

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `touchstart` event, not `click` for mobiles (check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/touchstart_event))

Answer (score 0):

add **display:none;** to the **on** css rule